# EF Nested/Un-nested Context Handling and Solution

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For the project I'm working on, I wanted to have methods that can handle both the presence or lack of an existing context to the database. This is because whenever I try to create a NEW context within an existing one it breaks. The obvious solution is to have 2 methods, one that takes in a context and one that doesn't, and just have one call the other, like so

```
public void Foo(int x){
    using(BarContext context = new BarContext()){
        Foo(context, x);
    }
}
public void Foo(BarContext context, int x){
    // Do whatever needs to be done with the db
}
```

However, it seems like a massive waste to write two entire methods for every thing I need to do.

I thought of a more elegant solution that only requires 1 method and still allows an existing context to be passed in if it exists, but creates a new one if it doesn't, seen here

```
public void Foo(int x, BarContext context = new BarContext()){
    using(context){
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

My concern is that I don't fully understand why the original issue, of creating a context within a context, happens. I don't know if its the context causing the problem or the 'using'. So I'm not sure if calling a 'using', on an existing context, within another 'using' will cause the same problem, seen here

```
public void FooBar(int x){
    using(BarContext context = new BarContext(){
        Foo(x, context);
        /* Within the Foo Method, where the same context is "used" a second time
            using(context){
                //Do Stuff
            }
        */
    }
}
```

So, my question is: will that work? Is it safe to use an existing context a second time within the original using statement? Or will everything break as before?

Comment: Is your input JSON or XML.  With xml the response is deserialized using XML serialization and the c# classes have to match the incoming response.

Comment: I don't know. My best guess is that its JSON, but I'm basing this on almost nothing. How do I check?

Comment: See following for differences : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization